# How to change my web-forms url from "Pages/Games.aspx?page=1" to "games/1"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, routes

I use VS 2017 I have simple project structure.

[image]

Using old-fashion web-forms I'm trying to add simple routing for my `Games.aspx`. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it would looks like this. Just creating new `RouteConfig` class in `App_Code` folder (this the place where I define routes)

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "games/{page}", "~/Games.aspx");
    }
}
```

And call that static method in `Global.asax` `Start` method.

```
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

But when I launch the project I get Not found error:

[image]

My `Games.aspx` works when I call it directly like `Pages/Games.aspx?page=1` but I don't want that stuff in my url. I tried to debug Start method, but it seems to be compiled by IIS or whatever. So, where am I wrong?

Comment: this link may help you https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx/

Comment: @NabeelKhan, it's kinda too complex solution for a such simple task.

Comment: routes.MapPageRoute("", "games/{page}", "~/Games.aspx"); are you maybe missing the pages here like routes.MapPageRoute("", "games/{page}", "~/Pages/Games.aspx");

Comment: @SehaxX, nope. That's not the case. I've tried even the whole path. That did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to handle this using the URL Rewrite Module:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteGames" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^games/(\d+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="Pages/Games.aspx?page={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

As @a.bajorinas eludes to, if you capture the `page` parameter in your route, then you have to modify code to use `Page.RouteData` instead of `Request.QueryString`. That isn't a big change really. But if you want to simply change the URL, it might be simplest to do so in web.config using the code below.

Comment: Thanks, strictly speaking that's not what I wanted but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate your code, as putting the `RouteConfig` class in `App_Code` wouldn't let me reference it in `Global.asmx`. What I did was put the method for maping routes inside my `Gloabal.asmx` Now it looks like this.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("", "games/{page}", "~/Games.aspx");
    }
}
```

When ever I would comment out the `RegisterRoutes()` method I would get the same error. Try this approach ant let me know if it helps. 
Also, to get the passed value in the `Game.aspx` you should use this `Page.RouteData.Values["page"]`

Comment: I've tried, unfortunately that did not work. But thanks for your approach.

Comment: I think its a combination of changing the route to `routes.MapPageRoute("", "games/{page}", "~/Pages/Games.aspx");` and also using `Page.RouteData.Values["page"]`.